# Android Notification FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL not working

Tags: android, service, notifications

HI all

I want cancel notification on click using code below but some reason it always shows notification in Ongoing section in Notifications area and could not clear too ..

```
  NOTIFICATION_ID = NOTIFICATION_ID + 1;
  Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
  PendingIntent pii = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent1, 0);
  Notification notification1 = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "test",
    System.currentTimeMillis());

  notification1.setLatestEventInfo(this,
    "test", "test", pii);

  notification1.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification1);
```

thanks

Comment: I notice in the answer `FLAG_AUTO_CLEAR` and `startForeground()` but nowhere in this code do I see it. Was this an typo and an assumption made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FLAG_AUTO_CLEAR` does not work with `startForeground()`.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please advise how could I fire notification than ?

Comment: Sorted.. I used NotificationManager's notify method and resolved my issue. Thanks so much

Comment: @Yousuf Qureshi: `startForeground()` is only to be used if you are trying to indicate that your service, while running, is part of the foreground user experience (e.g., a music player). General-purpose notifications use the `NotificationManager`.