# android service stops and again create when i close application

Tags: android, service, oncreate

I am developing an application in which i have implement the service.But when i exit from my application, service stops (but `onDestroy()` is never called) and then starts again (`OnCreate()` called).

Actually,I dont want to stop service once it is created regardless the state of application.
As service `onCreate()` is getting called again,service looses the previous processed data.I have tried `START_STICKY` but no luck.

so, How can i keep my service running?

here is my service code,

```
public class ddservice extends Service{

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("dservice", "onCreate");
                  /*here i am processing some important data in
                background thread*/  
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("ddservice", "onDestroy");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        super.onStart(intent, startid);
        Log.e("ddservice", "onStart");

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.e("ddservice", "onStartCommand");

        return START_STICKY;
    }   


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }   


}//service class ends here
```

And i am starting this service from  mainActivity as,

```
startService(new Intent(this, ddservice.class));
```

Comment: Can you add the code you use to start the service?

Comment: Hmm.. could be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211066/android-service-oncreate-is-called-multiple-times-without-calling-ondestroy?rq=1 Was solved by restarting ADB and emulator

Comment: restarting ADB did not work.

Comment: @Tapirboy:thank you for your weblink,running service in separate process solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should start your service as foreground `Service.startForeground(int, Notification)`

Comment: i implement the Service.startForeground(int, Notification) but causing the same issue.

Comment: i put http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687200/implement-startforeground-method-in-android code in onStart();

Comment: `onStart` deprecated since API level 5 and not invoked anymore. You should put it in `onCreate`

Comment: i put it in onCreate() but same issue.